# How to revert to legacy switching layout method?

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

I'm using [XNeur](http://xneur.ru) to quickly switch between input languages (Russian and English). Since Ubuntu 13.10 implemented new method of switching keyboard layout it is not possible for this software to operate correctly now.

How can I revert back to legacy keyboard switching method?

Some screenshots:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by editing properties of XNeur:

[image: xneur properties]

Also, do not forget to update XNeur from PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrew-crew-kuznetsov/xneur-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gxneur
```

This command might be needed if you want to set gXNeur's icon visible:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/gxneur/rendering_engine AppIndicator
```

Or, install [unity-systrayfix](https://launchpad.net/~timekiller/+archive/unity-systrayfix).